# Error al migrar en Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, linux, pdo

Me sale este error al querer migrar las tablas que nos da por defecto laravel. **Estoy ocupando Linux;**

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                            
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations)                                   



  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

Comment: Recien empezas con laravel? o ya has hecho migraciones y esto surgió de la nada?. un poco de contexto no estaría mal. Dicho esto y pos de la respuesta que te dieron abajo si tenes bien instalado LAMP y te sigue dando problemas. Laravel te provee Homestead(un box con toda las herramientas que necesitas para directamente sentarte a desarrollar). Para mi gusto, una de las cosas por que laravel se me hizo tan fácil de aprender

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar el controlador para Apache.

puedes usar:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Luego reinicias el servicio con:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Una vez hice un tutorial sobre la instalación de Laravel en NGINX puedes verlo en el [link](https://github.com/arie-cwhat/tutorials/blob/master/Nginx%20Install%20D8.markdown). Solo si usas NGINX, para Apache son mas o menos los mismos pasos, pero mas simples.

Comment: me dice que El paquete php5-mysql no está disponible

Comment: Puedes verificar que existan los repositorios correctos en `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`???

Comment: Tambien puedes probar `php-mysql` o `php-mysqlnd`. Tambien puedes poner `php` y luego la tecla tabulacion para ver todas las opciones.